# using process builder to get the stream of this process

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I'm using a common solution which is using the BufferedReader class in order to get the the input stream but it seems that if I can see the command console opening with the application running, I cannot get what's in there, there is no data in the variables and it's stuck at the readline() step, surely because the data is not flushed as the app is constantly running

```
public static void executeCommandOnLocalMachine(ProcessBuilder builder) throws Exception {
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process process = builder.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        Log.info(line);
        if(line.toLowerCase().contains("started"))
            break;
        line = reader.readLine();

    }
}
```

called by

```
public static String START_APPLICATION_MANAGER_COMMAND ="cd /D %VARENV%/../Application && start java -jar application.jar";


public static void startApplicationManager() throws Exception {
            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", GeneralConstants.START_APPLICATION_COMMAND);

    ProcessManager.executeCommandOnLocalMachine(builder);
}
```

Comment: Do you need the application to run in a console?

Comment: Shouldn't the forward slashes in the Windows path be doubled backslashes?  With `&&`, if the first command fails for some reason the second won't be attempted at all.

Answer (score 0):

if you use cmd `start`, cmd starts the process in a completely new window, so to access process output, simply leave off `start`.

Comment: the problem is that I want to be able to monitor also the console and if I'm not doing the "start" , I have no window opened at all and it's running in background (windows service I think)

Comment: @Rafale_Scarlet If you call [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) on your ProcessBuilder, all process output will be printed to the same place your Java program’s output is printed (including standard error, which will tell you if and why a process is failing).

Comment: while i think outputting to the console java was started from, I think inheritIO would break the "wait while started", so it will be a little bit more complicated, but not impossible.